# should I insert MemoryBarrier?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have such code:

```
.....
private volatile bool _connSharedDisposed;
......

    // Thread 1
    while (!_connSharedDisposed)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    CGate.Close();

    ......
    // Thread 2
    _connShared.Close();
    _listenerFutInfo.Close();
    _listenerFutInfo.Dispose();
    _listenerFutCommon.Close();
    _listenerFutCommon.Dispose();
    _connShared.Dispose();
    // insert Thread.MemoryBarrier here?
    _connSharedDisposed = true;
```

I'm afraid that `_connSharedDisposed = true` might be rearranged and receive `true` before calling `_connShared.Dispose()`. Is it possible? If my code doesn't work how to fix it? I guess I probably should insert MemoryBarrier to block "rearrange"

Also probably I should use `AutoResetEvent` instead of `bool volatile` variable...

Comment: `while (something) Thread.Sleep()` is an anti-pattern, you shouldn't do that. Can't you call `CGate.Close()` from thread 2? If not, you should probably use some synchronization primitive, like `ManualResetEventSlim`. EDIT: didn't read your last paragraph.

Comment: @svick the problem that in real world I have more complicated condition, like `while (!_connSharedDisposed || !connTransactionDispose || !connInfoDisposed)` How can I raise event when several conditions in several threads are all met?

Comment: There are several ways how to do that. Close to your code would be to use `Monitor.Wait()` instead of the sleep, and then call `Monitor.Pulse()` whenever any variable changes. Another option is to use something like `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` (or `Task.Wait()`, you can use `Task`s as synchronization constructs using `TaskCompletionSource`).

Answer (score 2):

If you've declared `_connSharedDisposed` with `volatile`, there's no need to use `MemoryBarrier`.

`volatile` makes each every write to a the field a volatile write and every read to the field a volatile read.  this means that the compiler cannot re-order instructions so that the order of accesses to the field remain the same in relation to one another.

On processors other than x86, `volatile` also causes any CPU cached writes to be flushed to RAM.  If you compile for x86, then `volatile` only applies to compiler optimizations.

If what you're trying to do is to cause a single thread to go into a wait state until something happens, then an auto reset event would be something you could use instead.  `AutoResetEvent` is the class that models this.  If you want to allow multiple threads to stop waiting, a manual reset event may be a better choice.  `ManualResetEvent` or `ManualResetEventSlim` (in .NET 4.0 or newer) are the classes that models that.